# 3 commutative rational polynomials?

Tags: polynomials, ring-theory, commutative-algebra, dynamical-systems, function-and-relation-composition

Let $A(x),B(x),C(x)$ be distinct univariate polynomials with rational coefficients of resp distinct degrees $a,b,c$.
Also $a,b,c$ are odd and larger than 1.

Let ** denote composition.

We want the polynomials to be commutative with each other ;

So the compositions are

$$A(B(x)) = B(A(x))$$
$$A(C(x)) = C(A(x))$$
$$B(C(x)) = C(B(x))$$

Also, there exists NO univariate polynomial with rational coefficients $D(x)$ of even degree >3 such that D commutes with one of A,B or C.

( Ofcourse $D(x)$ not equal to A,B or C )

What are examples of such polynomials ??

Notice sin( degree arcsin(x) ) does not work and neither does x^degree ; since they do have a D(x).

So the Chebyshev polynomials are NOT what we want.

Comment: Do you have an example of one odd-degree polynomial $A(x)$ that doesn't commute with any even-degree $D(x)$?

Comment: @RaviFernando I think x^7 + x + 1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By a the theorem of Ritt-Julia (see http://nyjm.albany.edu/j/2007/13-5p.pdf)
for commuting (non-linear) polynomials P,Q either they are similar to monomials or they are similar to Chebychev polynomials or:

$P^{\circ m} = Q^{\circ n}$

So lets choose A some nonlinear, non-monomial and non-Chebychev polynomial and set $B=A^{\circ 2}$ and $C=A^{\circ 3}$, so they obviously commute.
If there is an even degree D that commutes with A there need to exist m and n such that $A^{\circ m} = D^{\circ n}$, but then $\deg(A^{\circ m})=\deg(A)^m$ which means that it is uneven while $\deg(D^{\circ n}) = \deg(D)^n$ is even.

So there can not exist such a polynomial D (similarly for $A^{\circ 2}$ and $A^{\circ 3}$ which again are not monomials and not Chebychev polynomials).

Comment: For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: Thank you for the hint, I was looking for it but could not immediately find it. I will adapt my post accordingly.

Comment: Thanks. Still a bit confused by the linked paper ... I Read it fast though.